# Ajv custom error message for type

Tags: javascript, json, validation, ajv

i was exploring Ajv with ajv-errors for validating json schema and producing custom error messages. everything works as of now but i can't set custom error message for type for individual values.

```
const emailSchema = {
 type: 'object',
 required: ['foo', 'bar', 'car'],
 properties: {
  foo: { type: 'integer' },
  bar: { type: 'string' },
  car: { type: 'string' }
 },
 errorMessage: {
  type: 'should be an object',
  required: {
  foo: 'foo field is missing',
  bar: 'bar field is missing',
  car: 'car field is missing'
  }
 } 
};
```

outputs following error

```
[
    {
        "keyword": "type",
        "dataPath": "/foo",
        "schemaPath": "#/properties/foo/type",
        "params": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "message": "should be integer"
    },
    {
        "keyword": "errorMessage",
        "dataPath": "",
        "schemaPath": "#/errorMessage",
        "params": {
            "errors": [
                {
                    "keyword": "required",
                    "dataPath": "",
                    "schemaPath": "#/required",
                    "params": {
                        "missingProperty": "bar"
                    },
                    "message": "should have required property 'bar'"
                }
            ]
        },
        "message": "bar field is missing"
    },
    {
        "keyword": "errorMessage",
        "dataPath": "",
        "schemaPath": "#/errorMessage",
        "params": {
            "errors": [
                {
                    "keyword": "required",
                    "dataPath": "",
                    "schemaPath": "#/required",
                    "params": {
                        "missingProperty": "car"
                    },
                    "message": "should have required property 'car'"
                }
            ]
        },
        "message": "car field is missing"
    }
]
```

the first error object with message "should be integer", can i customize it like foo must be an Integer.
I am expecting something like below but it gives be schema error.

```
type : {
  foo : "foo must be an Integer"
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

You must declare `errorMessage` as keyword inside each of properties, see this example:

```js
const emailSchema = {
  type: 'object',
  required: ['foo', 'bar', 'car'],
  properties: {
    foo: {
      type: 'integer',
      errorMessage: {
        // In here must be errorMessage not errorMessages
        type: 'foo must be an Integer', // Your Custom Error Message
      },
    },
    bar: { type: 'string' },
    car: { type: 'string' },
  },
  errorMessages: {
    // Change from errorMessage to errorMessages
    type: 'should be an object',
    required: {
      foo: 'foo field is missing',
      bar: 'bar field is missing',
      car: 'car field is missing',
    },
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For use cases where we have some custom errorMessage or any other data, we have to use the schema path.
When we get the validation error, we also get the `error.keyword` in my case I had extra validation in if and else block as below

```
schema.allOf= Object.keys(bankCodes).map((key: any) => ({
    if: {
      properties: {
        routingCodeType1: { const: bankCodes[key].code },
      },
    },
    then: {
      properties: {
        routingCodeValue1: {
          pattern: bankCodes[key].pattern, //<-- this was cause of validation fail
          errorMessage: bankCodes[key].errorMessage,
        },
      },
    },
  }))
```

so in the `error.keyword` I would get `pattern` as well as `schemaPath=/#/allOf/2/then/properties/routingCodeValue1/pattern`

so basically I would have to use this schema path  to fetch the related data back from schema. Following code helped me with it

```
const getPatternMessage = (error: any, schema: any) => {
  if (error.keyword === 'pattern') {
    const fieldName = error.dataPath.substring(1); // routingCodeValue1
    const keyArr = error.schemaPath.split('/'); // ['#','allOf','2'..,'pattern']
    keyArr.pop(); // remove '#'
    keyArr.shift(); // remove 'pattern'
    const prop = keyArr.reduce((acc, key) => acc[key], schema);
/** 
prop contains  {
          pattern: '^[a-z]{9}$',
          errorMessage:'routingCodeValue1 should be 9 characters'
        },
*/
    return {
      [fieldName]: prop.errorMessage,
    };
  }
};
```

This way we are able to extract get custom errorMessage or any other data we want

> **Gist is to use the schemaPath property**